# How to keep variable's names when passing them to rownames()?

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I did run

```
my_matrix <- as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(days_a_week ~ id_survey+service, 
data = my_table))
```

How can I fix the rownames in that matrix if those are not properly displayed?

This is a part of my dataset (a survey of music services) that I made reproducible

```
service <- c("apple music", "spotify", "radio", "google play", "spotify", "spotify", "radio")
days_a_week <- c(1,2,1,1,3,2,1)
id_survey <- c("X38", "X38", "X38", "X22", "X22", "X50", "X50")

my_table <- as.data.frame(cbind(service,days_a_week))
setnames(my_table, colnames(my_table), c("service","days_a_week"))
my_table$id_survey <- id_survey
my_table$service <- as.character(my_table$service)
my_table$days_a_week <- as.numeric(as.character(my_table$days_a_week))

      service days_a_week id_survey
1 apple music           1       X38
2     spotify           2       X38
3       radio           1       X38
4 google play           1       X22
5     spotify           3       X22
6     spotify           2       X50
7       radio           1       X50

my_matrix <- as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(days_a_week ~ id_survey+service, 
data = my_table))

   apple music google play radio spotify
X1           1           0     1       2
X2           0           1     0       3
X3           0           0     1       2
```

Comment: `data.frame` use `make.names` so whenever there is a column name that starts with `numbers`, it appends `X` as prefix.  It is better to provide a reproducible example and expected output

Comment: I've added an example, thanks for the correction

Comment: I think you can directly create a data.frame with `my_table <- data.frame(service, days_a_week, id_survey, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` and then do the `xtabs`.  The `cbind` creates a `matrix` and `matrix` can hold only a single class, so `as.data.frame` will have all columns as `factor` (without `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`)

Comment: hmm... I did try that but the rownames are broken and appear as X1, X10, X100 ... instead of X38, 22, X50

Comment: I am getting X38, X22 and X50 from the example you showed

Comment: just change they line my_table <- as.data.frame(cbind(x1,x2)) to my_table <- as.data.frame(cbind(service,days_a_week) works. Not sure what x1,x2 are.

Comment: sorry, that was a typo I made while trying to make this readable

Comment: my solution was to close everything, restart the computer and it worked